# Facebook share Dialog that only post in groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I'm trying to created an option where visitors of my website, can share items in their Facebook groups. I know this is possible via the share dialog, but the option to post it on their own wall is standard selected. I don't like that.

Is there a way, that only the option to post it in a group is available? Or standard selected? Or is there another trick to accomplish this? So visitor can easily share items in the facebook groups?

Thanks for the advices.

Comment: There seems to be no parameter to define this kind of restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, you can only fire up those Dialogs but it´s completely up to the user to select a target, that´s how it is and should be.

You can see all parameters here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog